# PL/SQL Generate Random String from fixed set of characters

Tags: oracle, plsql

How do I generate a random string in PL/SQL from a fixed set of characters? For example:
I want to generate an alphanumeric string of length 10 which excludes certain characters and digits such as I,O,0 etc. I could not find a way to seed `DBMS_RANDOM.STRING()` with the required set. Is there a built in way in PL/SQl to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write such a function yourself - function that accepts particular set of characters mixes it up and returns the result. Here is an example. In this example [listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#CJABDFBD) function is used which is available only in **Oracle 11G R2** and higher.

1. Here is the simple function:

   ```
   SQL> create or replace function RandomString(p_Characters varchar2, p_length number)
     2  return varchar2
     3  is
     4    l_res varchar2(256);
     5  begin
     6    select substr(listagg(substr(p_Characters, level, 1)) within group(order by dbms_random.value), 1, p_length)
     7      into l_res
     8      from dual
     9    connect by level <= length(p_Characters);
    10    return l_res;
    11  end;
    12  /

    Function created
   ```
2. And here is how it works:

   ```
   SQL> select randomstring('1234567abcdefg', 10) res
     2    from dual
     3  connect by level <= 10
     4  /

   RES
   ----------
   caedg54f67
   f35eca6gb4
   4ae6f1c37b
   1c436g7a2b
   16e357bd2a
   564gca23ef
   d57c21bg36
   3gd62b4c1e
   31ea5cb472
   fe152bdga6

   10 rows selected
   ```

Answer (score -1):

According to oracle online documentation, there is a SEED procedure for the package

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_random.htm#i996798

Comment: I tried the seed procedure. It does not work for random string.

Comment: -1 seeding the random number generator has nothing to do with this question